# Data inconsistency in multithreaded Python code

Tags: python, multithreading, singleton

First time SO user here. I have a problem with my "thread-safe" Python singleton. The class stores data that is only **read** by the worker threads. The main thread updates some of the data. I was under the impression that a singleton will ensure that my worker threads will have access to the same data. However, in reality, some of the threads still process "old" data (pre data change in the main thread).

I used the singleton implementation from https://refactoring.guru:

```
from threading import Lock

class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}
    _lck = Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        with cls._lck:
            if cls not in cls._instances:
                instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
                cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Storage(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def __init__(self, shared=None):
        self._shared = shared

    @property
    def shared(self):
        return self._shared

    def refresh(self, update):
        if update:
            self._shared['managed'] = update
            logger.debug("[+] Shared data refreshed.")
```

The `refresh()` method is only called from the main thread. The worker threads read the dictionary via the `shared` property.

Is this the correct approach? I am afraid not, since the data is not consistent among the worker threads. Can anybody help me understand what I am doing wrong and why the data is not updated for all threads?

Thank you

**Update**

After more investigation and reading, it turns out, the Singleton is not the problem. My problem (and the part I didn't mention because I did't think of it at first) is rooted in the different gunicorn worker processes. So the thread(s) in the worker process that applies the data update has the correct data and the others don't. I will have to think about how I can synchronize the data between workers.

Comment: All you've ensured is that the workers use the same singleton. You haven't actually synchronized anything beyond that.

Comment: The use of a singleton provides no benefit here.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: @alaniwi thanks for spotting the typos early. I should've seen that before posting.

Comment: @Headroom you're welcome, small thing...